# Visualization of tables in neo4j (spoon-neo4j)

Tags: javascript, neo4j, bookmarklet

I want to use a [script](https://github.com/jexp/spoon-neo4j) to build histograms. 
Does it work for you? It does not work for me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I added the javascript line in the browser bookmarks:

```
javascript:$.getScript('https://cdn.rawgit.com/jexp/spoon-neo4j/master/spoon.js');
```

I tried using script:

```
javascript:(function(a){a.body.appendChild(a.createElement("script")).src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jexp/spoon-neo4j/master/spoon.js"})(document);
```

But it does not work either.
I want to build such graphics in the browser

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more context around what you're trying to achieve? You've asked multiple questions, within the same question - which will likely result in the question being flagged or closed. I suggest taking a look at the guidelines on how to ask questions on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

I have memorized

```
:play spoon.html
```

as a bookmark within the neo4j browser (the star button).